# Why is base method being called once overridden in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

I have a situation similar to below (code is NOT exact, just to get my point across).  When I call `D.A()` I expect the word `"Desc"` to be printed, but instead `"Base"` is printed.

```
class Base {
public:
  void A() { B(); }
  virtual void B() { cout << "Base"; }
}

class Descendant : public Base {
public:
  virtual void B() overriden { cout << "Desc"; }
}

main () {
  Descendant D;
  D.A();
}
```

There must be something conceptual I'm missing here.  Should `D.A()` cause `"Desc"` to be printed?  If not, why?

Comment: [can't reproduce](https://ideone.com/4Yanwp) using the exact code shown (after fixing typos in it). Calling `D.A()` displays `"Desc"` as expected. The ONLY way that would not happen is if either 1) `A()`/`B()` is being called in the context of the `Base` constructor/destructor, or 2) if `Descendant::B()` does not actually override `Base::B()` (which is what the `override` keyword is designed to catch at compile-time). In the latter case, make sure you are actually using `override` in your real code (in pre-C++11, there is no `override`).

Comment: It's `override`, not `overriden`. Which further solidifies this code wasn't tested and doesn't reproduce your problem. Create a proper [mcve] please.

Comment: @Storyteller - as I said in the question, this is not code to compile, just a way of expressing my question.  It's not supposed to compile

Comment: @Remy - after your comments I did some chasing I realized that A is in fact the constructor.  That explains why the descendant B was never called.  (Took me a while to find that).

Comment: @TSG then you should post that as an answer, or just close the question.

Comment: @Remy - I just had to wait 24 hours to post

Answer (score 1):

There is an important error in the question.  The method A is in fact the constructor of the Base class.  And it makes sense that the constructor can't call any methods (even virtual) of derived classes since those derived classes don't exist yet.

When A is a non-ctor, it works as expected.